# Percentage on y-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Using this list of lists as a dataset:

```
my list= [[],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     ['EMF'],
     ['body'],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     ['water', 'juice'],
     ['What', 'are', 'u', 'doing'],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     ['EVENT'],
     ['christmas'],
     [],
     ['shalala'],
     ['happy'],
     []]
```

I would like to plot the percentage on the y-axis of this data compared to the total.
I have tried with this:

```
cnt = Counter(chain.from_iterable(df)) # df is the dataframe generated from the list above
plt.bar(*zip(*cnt.most_common(20)))
plt.xticks(rotation=60)
plt.show()
```

The problem is that I do not know how to the the percentage. I hope you can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try `value_counts`

```
pd.Series(l).explode().dropna().\
      value_counts(normalize=True).sort_values(ascending=False).head(10).plot(kind='bar')
```